# Parsing json directly using input stream

Tags: android, json, gson, android-parser

I am doing a api call and in response i am getting json. So for that I want to parse it directly through input stream so that there would not be need of storing it in memory. 
For this I am trying to use JSONReader but that i am unable use for api's less than 11.
So i dont know how to proceed with. I want it to be done from 2.0 version onwards. Even parsing through JsonReader is not working.
I was thing of having GSON parser but i am not getting how to implement the same with Inputstream.

EDIT:
My code for the same:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

try {
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
          StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
          int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
          Log.e("123", "Status code ----------- "+statusCode);
          if (statusCode == 200) { 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();


            // for showing it on textview i am storing in in builder
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
              builder.append(line);
            }

//////////// 
            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            reader.setLenient(true);
            readGson(reader);
          } else {
            Log.e("TAG", "Failed to download file");
          }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
      }

private void readGson(JsonReader reader) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("TAG", "inidde readgson"+reader);

                 try {
                     Log.e("TAG", "inside try");
                    reader.beginObject();
                    Log.e("123", "inside try  ");
                     while(reader.hasNext()){
                         Log.e("TAG", "reader values"+reader);
                         String name = reader.nextName();
                         if (name.equals("max_id")) {
                             long max_id = reader.nextLong();
                             Log.e("TAG", "sdbfhsajfgsdjbgksdfjv------------------"+max_id);
                           }  else {
                               Log.e("TAG", "c skfnvklsfvn skip value");
                             reader.skipValue();
                           }
                     }
                     reader.endObject();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e("TAG", "inside catch");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

output:

```
    01-28 10:20:53.519: E/TAG(420): Status code ----------- 200
01-28 10:20:53.679: E/TAG(420): inidde readgsonJsonReader at line 1 column 1
01-28 10:20:53.679: E/TAG(420): inside try
01-28 10:20:53.679: E/TAG(420): inside catch
01-28 10:20:53.679: W/System.err(420): java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1
01-28 10:20:53.689: W/System.err(420):  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:954)
01-28 10:20:53.689: W/System.err(420):  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.consumeNonExecutePrefix(JsonReader.java:405)
01-28 10:20:53.689: W/System.err(420):  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:364)
01-28 10:20:53.689: W/System.err(420):  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.expect(JsonReader.java:337)
01-28 10:20:53.689: W/System.err(420):  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:322)
01-28 10:20:53.689: W/System.err(420):  at com.example.httpconnectiondemo.MainActivity.readGson(MainActivity.java:136)
01-28 10:20:53.699: W/System.err(420):  at com.example.httpconnectiondemo.MainActivity.readTwitterFeed(MainActivity.java:116)
01-28 10:20:53.699: W/System.err(420):  at com.example.httpconnectiondemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
01-28 10:20:53.699: W/System.err(420):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-28 10:20:53.699: W/System.err(420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-28 10:20:53.699: W/System.err(420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-28 10:20:53.699: W/System.err(420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-28 10:20:53.699: W/System.err(420):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-28 10:20:53.699: W/System.err(420):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 10:20:53.699: W/System.err(420):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-28 10:20:53.699: W/System.err(420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-28 10:20:53.710: W/System.err(420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 10:20:53.710: W/System.err(420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-28 10:20:53.710: W/System.err(420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-28 10:20:53.710: W/System.err(420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-28 10:20:53.710: W/System.err(420):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're using the `content` stream in a wrong way. Look at the marked lines:

```
InputStream content = entity.getContent();

// (1)
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
String line;
while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
}

// (2)
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
reader.setLenient(true);
readGson(reader);
```

The issue here is that you wrap the same stream twice (on marked line).

- After first wrap, you go through the stream collecting the lines and concatenating them in a `builder`. You must be aware that effectively the `bReader` is just a wrapper around the `content` stream. So while you are collecting the lines, the content from the `content` stream is eaten. So, the condition `(line = ...) != null` is `false` when the `content` stream is at the end of input.
- Then you wrap the `content` stream again - for parsing JSON contents. But the stream **is already at the end of input here**, so there is nothing to consume by the JSON reader. And that exactly is the meaning of the line: `java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1` of your exception.

What you have to do is to read through the `content` stream *only once*. So, you have several options here:

- Don't save received contents to a `String`. You delete the first wrap and the loop which builds the response string using a `builder`. If that's not an option then I recommend:
- Save the whole response to a `String`. Note: you can use the `EntityUtils` class for this since it will do the work for you:

  ```
  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

  // All the work is done for you here :)
  String jsonContent = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

  // Create a Reader from String
  Reader stringReader = new StringReader(jsonContent);

  // Pass the string reader to JsonReader constructor
  JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(stringReader);
  reader.setLenient(true);
  readGson(reader);

  ...
  // at the end of method return the JSON response
  return jsonContent;
  ```

Comment: Nice answer, dude. It was very clarifying, but something really get me confused: why did you advice to dont save something to string ( what I consider a good software design choice ) and at the next topic you advice to save the whole response to a String.

Comment: @Miere you're right, thank you for pointing out that inconsistency :) let me explain what I meant. my advice about not holding the content of the response in a `String` comes from my experience with Android devices - some of them have pretty low memory limits, e.g. 16M/application. now imagine an application which tries saving JSON response that has, let's say, 20M... the application would simply crash. I don't know what devices OP is targeting and that's why I wrote that 1st point. however, there are cases in which you know this scenario won't happen and you can safely go with the 2nd point.