# Error Deserializing objects using fromJson?

Tags: android, json, gson, getjson

I use gson to read my json from mysql. but when i run app it return value null. i dont know what about error, because when i run app in local with the the same mysql it's working. But when i run in host, It return null. Please help me!

```
{"group":
[{"category_id":"15","title":"Zing card - Zing xu"},
{"category_id":"14","title":"Th\u1ebb Gate - FPT"},
{"category_id":"20","title":"Vcoin - VTC - Audition"},
{"category_id":"21","title":"Garena"},
{"category_id":"32","title":"Mobay card"},
{"category_id":"33","title":"BIT Card"},
{"category_id":"34","title":"Oncash"}],
"product":
[
{"id":"39","group_id":"22","name":"Oncash","price":{"USD":9,"AUD":12.756909992913,"VND":195000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/oncach-e3bb9fa75d.gif","sku":"ONCASH200"},
{"id":"87","group_id":"33","name":"TH\u1eba BIT 5 TRI\u1ec6U","price":{"USD":252.42,"AUD":357.7888022679,"VND":4950000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/uwrki7jx-6198ed1975.gif","sku":"Bit5M"},
{"id":"88","group_id":"33","name":"TH\u1eba BIT 2 TRI\u1ec6U","price":{"USD":100.98,"AUD":143.13253012048,"VND":1980000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/91intahd-b42a80c01d.gif","sku":"Bit2M"},
{"id":"89","group_id":"33","name":"TH\u1eba BIT 1 TRI\u1ec6U","price":{"USD":50.48,"AUD":71.552090715804,"VND":990000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/nwd03knt-264a8d02fe.gif","sku":"Bit1M"},
{"id":"92","group_id":"33","name":"TH\u1eba BIT 500K","price":{"USD":25.23,"AUD":35.761871013466,"VND":495000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/8hxdajdl-9c8001602e.gif","sku":"Bit500K"},
{"id":"90","group_id":"33","name":"TH\u1eba BIT 200K","price":{"USD":10.08,"AUD":14.287739192062,"VND":198000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/ql3cn6iu-b4d8c3b407.gif","sku":"Bit200K"},
{"id":"91","group_id":"33","name":"TH\u1eba BIT 100K","price":{"USD":5.03,"AUD":7.1296952515946,"VND":100000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/oupebhyo-0a61ca65b2.gif","sku":"Bit100K"},
{"id":"93","group_id":"33","name":"TH\u1eba BIT 50K","price":{"USD":2.69,"AUD":3.8128986534373,"VND":50000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/zvznjqnz-52c80ccfe6.gif","sku":"Bit50K"},
{"id":"121","group_id":"33","name":"Th\u1ebb BIT 20k","price":{"USD":1.06,"AUD":1.5024805102764,"VND":20000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/the-bit-20k-6b4035c02d.gif","sku":"Bit20K"},
{"id":"80","group_id":"32","name":"TH\u1eba MOBAY 500K","price":{"USD":25.23,"AUD":35.761871013466,"VND":495000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/u5jywcz0-55285adfd7.gif","sku":"Mobay500K"},
{"id":"83","group_id":"32","name":"TH\u1eba MOBAY 200K","price":{"USD":10.08,"AUD":14.287739192062,"VND":198000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/db8f1s3y-170821fbe1.gif","sku":"Mobay200K"},
{"id":"82","group_id":"32","name":"TH\u1eba MOBAY 100K","price":{"USD":5.03,"AUD":7.1296952515946,"VND":100000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/57mzcwfk-40f4d60542.gif","sku":"Mobay100K"},
{"id":"85","group_id":"32","name":"TH\u1eba MOBAY 50K","price":{"USD":2.69,"AUD":3.8128986534373,"VND":50000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/hf8jilab-11ed516444.gif","sku":"Mobay50K"},
{"id":"84","group_id":"32","name":"TH\u1eba MOBAY 20K","price":{"USD":1.06,"AUD":1.5024805102764,"VND":20000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/pvrh3jey-dd0894e849.gif","sku":"Mobay20K"},
{"id":"53","group_id":"20","name":"Vcoin 200k","price":{"USD":10.08,"AUD":14.287739192062,"VND":198000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/v200-61d2763add.gif","sku":"VNS-VCOIN200K"},
{"id":"37","group_id":"20","name":"Vcoin 20k","price":{"USD":1.06,"AUD":1.5024805102764,"VND":20000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/v20-e0f120eefd.gif","sku":"vcoin20k"},
{"id":"118","group_id":"20","name":"Vcoin 1 tri\u1ec7u","price":{"USD":50.48,"AUD":71.552090715804,"VND":990000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/rpwzfkfy-655e715791.gif","sku":"VCOIN1TRIEU"},
{"id":"45","group_id":"14","name":"Gate 5 tri\u1ec7u","price":{"USD":252.42,"AUD":357.7888022679,"VND":4950000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/gate5trieu-c43aa69716.gif","sku":"GATE5000k"},
{"id":"44","group_id":"14","name":"Gate 2 tri\u1ec7u","price":{"USD":100.98,"AUD":143.13253012048,"VND":1980000},"images":"http:\/\/vnsupermark.com\/uploads\/catalog\/gate2trieu-091d584fce.gif","sku":"thegate2trieu"}
]}
```

Function return myjson

```
public ResListProduct getListProducts(Context context) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ResListProduct resListProduct = null;
        resListProduct = new ResListProduct();

        try {

            String urlApi = Store.getInstances(context).getA();
            // URL

            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            int i = MainActivity.getVariable();
            // all product

            if (i == 1) {
                params.put("command", "get_products");
            }
            if (i > 1) {
                ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
                s = MainActivity.getnamegrouptrem();
                for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
                    String[] titleActionbars = s.toArray(new String[s.size()]);
                    params.put("command", "get_product");
                    params.put("cagory", titleActionbars[j]);
                }

                // if (i == 9) {
                // params.put("command", "get_product");
                // params.put("cagory", String.valueOf(21));
                // }// test autogen memu
            }

            InputStream stream = retrieveStream(urlApi, params, false, null,
                    null);
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            //Printf JSON
//          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
//          String read;
//          while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {                
//              System.out.println("JSON" + read);
//          }



            // parse json to get list product
            resListProduct = gson.fromJson(reader, ResListProduct.class);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            sendException(context,
                    "getListProduct: " + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }

        return resListProduct;
    }
```

class object

```
    public class ResListProduct {
        @SerializedName("product")
        private List<Product> products;
        @SerializedName("group")
        private List<GroupProduct> groups;

        public ResListProduct() {
        }

        public List<Product> getProducts() {
            return products;
        }

        public List<GroupProduct> getGroups() {
            return groups;
        }

    }

public class Product implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6061052006970796100L;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String idProduct;
    @SerializedName("group_id")
    private String groupId;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String nameProduct;
    @SerializedName("price")
    private Price priceProduct;
    @SerializedName("images")
    private String urlImagesProduct;
    @SerializedName("sku")
    private String skuProduct;
    @SerializedName("names")
    private String names;

    // quantity for each product
    private int quantity;

    // title group product
    private String titleGroup;

    public Product(String titleGroup) {
        this.titleGroup = titleGroup;
    }

    public String getIdProduct() {
        return idProduct;
    }

    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public String getNameProduct() {
        return nameProduct;
    }

    public Price getPriceProduct() {
        return priceProduct;
    }

    public String getUrlImagesProduct() {
        return urlImagesProduct;
    }

    public String getSkuProduct() {
        return skuProduct;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getTitleGroup() {
        return titleGroup;
    }

    public String getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    public void setNames(String names) {
        this.names = names;
    }


}

public class GroupProduct {
    @SerializedName("category_id")
    public String groupId;
    @SerializedName("title")
    public String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public GroupProduct() {
    }

    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the accepted answer here help you? Basically it States that the stream is consumed twice and thus the reader object doesn't have anything in it to parse. 
[Parsing json directly using input stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555584/parsing-json-directly-using-input-stream)

Comment: yes, but when i run the same data in host, It's working. i have read the json ok, but when i parse, it return to null.